# C++ random bitwise behavior

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

**INTENTION** -> A program that adds even numbers only within a range

**Strange behavior** -> the logical statement is incorrect for adding even numbers, instead the logical statement is correct for adding odd numbers, but the sum of even numbers is the result. As we all know, `num & 1` returns true if num is odd, and false if num is even.

**Question** -> Check my logical statement in the code. Why is the increment of n inline with the logical operator inverting the return value and summing even numbers (which is intended, but unexpected for this logical statement)?

```
//program to print sum of even numbers
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int n = {0}, result = {0};
    while(n < 99) result += n++ & 1 ? n : 0;
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

I was experiencing some random behavior when attempting a simple coding implementation of a bitwise odd number detection.  `num & 1` 
This is returning the desired and appropriate value of even nums between 0 and 100, when I'm not using any negation. such as `~num & 1` . Can someone explain to me why the negation isn't necessary, and why its returning even values? Is there some extra behavior to the n++ happening?

**NOTE:** I understand the syntax is obtuse, that was sort of my intention, to be as obtuse as possible for the sake of experimenting with the language a bit. I'm not asking for a style critique.

**Examples**

https://repl.it/KG8Z/1 < this should print odd, but *what is the unintended side-effect of the `++` operator that is making it print even numbers?*

https://repl.it/KG8Z/0  < c++

https://repl.it/KGId/3 < python

I was expecting to need to use the bitwise not operator in c++ to get the desired result, but the results are the same despite the absence of a logical not. How to explain this *odd* behavior?

Comment: Are you asking us why your own code worked? What did you think when you wrote it? What were your expectations? Why do you think negation is necessary?

Comment: because ```if(num & 1) { // num is odd }```  and ```if(num & ~1) { //num is even} ``` this is pretty standard stuff. What I thought when I wrote it is, hmm, i'm getting the odd sum, what happens if I remove the negation? Seems to work, but why? Check the python solution, that's the expected behavior from negation.

Comment: By the way, it is better to do bitwise operations with hex values so instead of `1` it would be `0x00000001`.

Comment: What do you find odd about it? What did you expect and how does it differ from what you expect? The question isnt quite clear. "why the negation isn't necessary" not necessary for what?

Comment: ```n&1``` is odd. not even. but its adding the even values. That's unexpected.... It's not hard guys. I laid it out plain for you. I just don't know WHY it's adding evens and not odds.

Comment: https://repl.it/KG8Z/1 this should print odd numbers, but there's something funky happening with incrementing n within the bitwise comparison. THAT is the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Do you know *anything* about binary numbers? If not then you better learn that. Then perhaps about how the suffix `++` operator works as well.

Comment: Derp. That isn't the point. I've demonstrated that I understand binary. I'm asking specifically about the unintended side-effects of the ++ operator within the bitwise comparison.

Comment: what is unintended? We cannot read your mind so you have to tell us what is your intention

Comment: ```oddnum & 1``` returns 1, and is therefore true. so ```if (oddistrue) -> print odd```  but what's happening is ```if oddistrue -> print even``` how is this not strange to you all?

Comment: what do you mean "READ MY MIND"??? I mentioned that the INTENDED BEHAVIOR IS TO ADD EVENS. But the logical statement isn't correct to add even numbers. its correct for odds. which is strange, because its doing what i intended, adding even numbers, but the logical statement should be adding odd numbers. 

how is this hard?

I even included in the comments of the program "program for adding even numbers"

Comment: I am confused. What code are you talking about? The one in the question has a single `cout` that prints a sum, but not all even/odd numbers

Comment: Do you realize that when N is odd, N + 1 is even?

Comment: Sergey, I forgot my incrementing order of operations. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's the [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) in C++ you want to learn about then? For a conditional expression the left-side of the `?` is fully evaluated (including side-effects) before the right side of `?` is evaluated. That means if `n` is odd (rather, bit `0` is set) then `n + 1` is the result of the expression, otherwise it's `0` (but `n` is still increased)

Comment: great resources. this was useful. 

Thanks

Comment: just a correction: `if(num & ~1) { //num is even}` is not true. It should be `if (!(num&1)) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When

```
n++ & 1
```

executes, lets expect `n` is odd number at the moment, condition is true.

Post incrementation is applied and `n` is even when

```
result += n
```

executes. Thats why its counting even numbers instead of odd. Modify code to

```
while(n < 99) result += !(n++ & 1) ? n : 0;
```

and it will count odd one's.

Comment: Oh, I see. So if I preincrement, then a negation would be necessary, but its returning true then incrementing to the next number.

Comment: If you pre-increment you will lose first number and count 99 :) Glad you understands now :-)

Answer (score 0):

[`[expr.cond]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#1):

> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is
>   contextually converted to bool. It is evaluated and if it is true, the
>   result of the conditional expression is the value of the second
>   expression, otherwise that of the third expression. Only one of the
>   second and third expressions is evaluated. **Every value computation and
>   side effect associated with the first expression is sequenced before
>   every value computation and side effect associated with the second or
>   third expression.**

Thus, `n` is "selected" on odd `n`s in the condition, but at that point, it's already incremented (even).

---

`n & ~1` is not the same as `!(n & 1)`.

Comment: I am not sure if OP has any slightest idea of a `sequence point`.